# How to pass id from javascript function to apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

Hi I am implementing live agent in our organization and I have created a visualforce page to get the object id focused in subtab. I am trying to pass the object id to my apex controller to use for case creation and other operations. Below is my code, in alert i am getting the record id but it is not passing it to apex controller.

**VF PAGE:**

```
<apex:page controller="ShowCaseInConsole" title=" End Chat Page ">
    <script> 
        var previousOnload = window.onload; window.onload = function()     
        { 
            if (previousOnload) { previousOnload(); }
            testGetFocusedSubtabObjectId(); 
        } 
    </script>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/33.0/integration.js"/> 
    <apex:form >
        <!-- <a href="#" onClick="endChat();return false;" >End Chat</a> --> 
        <apex:actionFunction name="testGetFocusedSubtabObjectId" action="{!Show}" onComplete="alert('After apex method');">
            <apex:param name="cid" value="" assignTo="{!ConId}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testGetFocusedSubtabObjectId() {
            sforce.console.getFocusedSubtabObjectId(showObjectId);
        }

        var showObjectId = function showObjectId(result) {
            // Display the object ID
            alert ('Object ID: ' + result.id);
        }; 
    </script> 
</apex:page>
```

**APEX CONTROLLER :**

```
public PageReference Show() {
    String contactid= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Cid');
    system.debug('contact id from javascript function---'+contactid);
}
```

How do I access the id? thank you for any help.

Below is the code for updated function for which I would like to return the value, in Alert I am getting the value but it is not returning it to action function.

```
     function primarytabid(){
    //sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(showTabId);
    sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(showTabId);}
    var showTabId = function showTabId(result) {

            //Display the primary tab IDs

            alert('Primary Tab IDs: ' + result.id);
            var primaryTab = result.id;
            testGetDetailsByPrimaryTabId(primaryTab)
            };
       function testGetDetailsByPrimaryTabId(primary) {
        var primaryTabId = primary;
        alert('set value to variable'+primaryTabId);
        sforce.console.chat.getDetailsByPrimaryTabId(primaryTabId, getDetailsSuccess); 
    }

    function getDetailsSuccess(result) {
        //Report whether accepting the chat was succesful
       if (result.success == true) {
            console.log(result);
            alert('result'+result);
            chatKey = result.details.chatKey;
            alert('The chatKey for this chat is: ' + chatKey);
            var value=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.details.customDetails.length; i++) { 
                value.push(result.details.customDetails[i].value);
            }
            alert('The custom details : '+value.join(''));
        } else {
            alert('Getting the details was not Succesful');
        }
        AddcustomDetailValue(value.join(''));
    };
```

I am calling `PrimaryTabId()` function here and in my action function I am calling `AddcustomDetailValue()`. how do I return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass the value you want to set into the function when you call it:

`testGetFocusedSubtabObjectId('Id');`

Replace 'Id' with your object id. That will set the `ConId` property in your controller to the value you pass in and you'll able to access it using that.

**EDIT:**

You would do something similar to pass in the result of a function. Using your example it would be:

```
var showObjectId = function showObjectId(result) {
            // Display the object ID
            testGetFocusedSubtabObjectId(result.id);
        };
```

Comment: Hi  John, thank you for your response. I want to access the return value from the javascript function and use it in controller. will passing ID to the function help me do so?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Which javascript function are you getting a value from to use in the controller?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        function testGetFocusedSubtabObjectId() {
            sforce.console.getFocusedSubtabObjectId(showObjectId);
        }

        var showObjectId = function showObjectId(result) {
            // Display the object ID
            alert ('Object ID: ' + result.id);
        }; 
    </script>`
this function gives me the value I need to use in my controller. I need to access the result.id value in my controller and do operation.

Comment: Got it. I updated the answer with a clearer example given your comments.

Comment: Thank you for the update but that sends the function in an infinite loop and also the actionfunction is not calling SHOW method from the controller.

Comment: That's because the name of your actionFunction is the same as the name of an existing function: `testGetFocusedSubtabObjectId` is defined as both an actionFunction and in your javascript on the page. The actionFunction control creates a javascript function that you call elsewhere in your code. Since you have it defined in your code elsewhere it's overriding the code created by the actionFunction declaration and ends up calling itself over and over. You need to rename one of the two functions.

Comment: Thank you so much John. That worked. I marked the reply as answer. thank you again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @JohnTowers, I also have other function where this is failing, I am getting the values I need in alert but it is not returning to actionfunction. I have added the new code to question. please respond if possible.